# Cannot run a Javascript code from Codebehind in an Aspx page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

Hi I have a web form where I have to call a javascript function from the codebehind file. It was working fine until I added an update panel to the page.
The code that I was using was

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "OpenExe()", true);
```

I researched a bit and I came to know that if we add a scriptmanager/update panel in a page we have to use

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "Sample", "OpenExe()", true);
```

I used this and also I used

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(@"<script language='javascript'>");
        sb.Append(@"var cmdShell = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell');");
        sb.Append(@"var myPath = '\'C:\\Temp\\stacks.exe\\'');");        
        sb.Append(@"</script>");

        if (!ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("JSScript"))
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "JSScript", sb.ToString());
        }
```

I also tried

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel1, typeof(UpdatePanel), "Sample", "OpenExe()", true);
```

But the javascript isnt executing. Can someone tell me what may be wrong with the code? Let me know if you want to see more piece of codes. Thank in advance

Comment: are you using an update panel in your page ?

Comment: @AliShahrokhi yes after adding the update panel onbly the code stopped working

Comment: with the above solutions can you try to use `alert('test');` instead of `OpenExe()` on your code? to make sure there is no js corruption on your function.

Answer (score 1):

OK if you have an Update panel try this instead:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(yourupdatepanel, this.GetType(), "Sample", "OpenExe()", true);
```

place your updatepanel control id on the first argument

Comment: can you update your code with its scope, then I can see your code in details.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to set the updatemode of the updatepanel to "always".
or if the code is into a button click handler, you can add trigger  for the updatepanel with the controleid attr the id of the button.

`<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlDetailsScratchCard" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>
      </ContentTemplate>
     <Triggers><asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="buttonID" /> </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>`

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlDetailsScratchCard" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
<ContentTemplate>
</ContentTemplate>
```

Comment: if you can, show me the source code of the update panel , and the event throwing the script..

Answer (score -1):

Java Script Code Execute only after your whole program gets executed. if you have any errors in your C# code,Script called from Code behind wont works.Also if you call Script from your Code behind. only one script gets executed for one event.